# How to disable all formally controls?

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I have a long form that looks similar to the following:

```
...

export function directoryForm(
  countries: CountryModel[],
  dealers: DealerModel[],
  translate: TranslateService
): FormlyFieldConfig[] {
  return [
    {
      type: 'stepper',
      fieldGroup: [
        {
          templateOptions: { label: translate.instant('shared.house') },
          fieldGroup: [
            {
              fieldGroupClassName: 'md:flex',
              fieldGroup: [
                {
                  key: 'name',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1 mr-2',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.name'),
                    required: true,
                    disabled: true
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'distributor',
                  type: 'select',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.dealer'),
                    required: true,
                    options: dealers,
                    labelProp: 'name',
                    valueProp: 'id',
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              fieldGroupClassName: 'md:flex',
              fieldGroup: [
                {
                  key: 'country',
                  type: 'select',
                  className: 'flex-1 mr-2',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.country'),
                    required: true,
                    options: countries,
                    labelProp: 'name',
                    valueProp: 'country-code',
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'city',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.city'),
                    required: true,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              fieldGroupClassName: 'md:flex',
              fieldGroup: [
                {
                  key: 'contact',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1 mr-2',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.contact'),
                    required: true,
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'address',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.address'),
                    required: true,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              fieldGroupClassName: 'md:flex',
              fieldGroup: [
                {
                  key: 'telephone',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1 mr-2',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.telephone'),
                    required: true,
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'fax',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1 mr-2',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.fax'),
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'email',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.email'),
                    required: true,
                    pattern: emailPattern,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              fieldGroupClassName: 'md:flex gap-2',
              fieldGroup: [
                {
                  key: 'website',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.website'),
                    pattern: urlPattern,
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'facebook',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: 'Facebook',
                    pattern: urlPattern,
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'twitter',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: 'Twitter',
                    pattern: urlPattern,
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'instagram',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: 'Instagram',
                    pattern: urlPattern,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              key: 'isOperative',
              type: 'select',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant('model.is-operative'),
                required: true,
                options: [
                  { value: 1, label: translate.instant('shared.yes') },
                  { value: 2, label: translate.instant('shared.no') },
                ],
              },
            },
            {
              key: 'area',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant('model.area'),
                required: true,
              },
            },
            {
              key: 'description',
              type: 'textarea',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant('model.description'),
                required: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          templateOptions: {
            label: translate.instant('model.owner.self'),
          },
          fieldGroup: [
            {
              key: 'owner.name',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant('model.owner.name'),
                required: true,
              },
            },
            {
              key: 'owner.contact',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant('model.owner.contact'),
                required: true,
              },
            },
            {
              key: 'owner.address',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant('model.owner.address'),
                required: true,
              },
            },
            {
              fieldGroupClassName: 'md:flex',
              fieldGroup: [
                {
                  key: 'owner.telephone',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-2 mr-2',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant(
                      'model.owner.telephone'
                    ),
                    required: true,
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'owner.fax',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-2 mr-2',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.owner.fax'),
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'owner.email',
                  type: 'input',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant('model.owner.email'),
                    required: true,
                    pattern: emailPattern,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          templateOptions: {
            label: translate.instant('model.data.self'),
          },
          fieldGroup: [
            {
              key: 'data.status',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant('model.data.status'),
                required: true,
              },
            },
            {
              key: 'data.documents',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant(
                  'model.data.documents'
                ),
                required: true,
              },
            },
            {
              key: 'data.item1',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant(
                  'model.data.item1'
                ),
                required: true,
              },
            },
            {
              key: 'data.item2',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant(
                  'model.data.item2'
                ),
                required: true,
              },
            },
            {
              key: 'data.approved',
              type: 'input',
              templateOptions: {
                label: translate.instant(
                  'model.data.approved'
                ),
                required: true,
              },
            },
            {
              fieldGroupClassName: 'md:flex',
              fieldGroup: [
                {
                  key: 'data.startDate',
                  type: 'datepicker',
                  className: 'flex-1 mr-2',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant(
                      'model.data.start-date'
                    ),
                    required: true,
                  },
                },
                {
                  key: 'data.openingDate',
                  type: 'datepicker',
                  className: 'flex-1',
                  templateOptions: {
                    label: translate.instant(
                      'model.data.opening-date'
                    ),
                    required: true,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```

I use this field definition in the context of creating and editing a record. I now need to display the same form in detail view but with all fields disabled. I know that individually you can do it like this

```
{
    key: 'somekey',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'Some label',
        disabled: true, // <--
        required: true
    }
}
```

How to disable all formally controls?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got to solve this problem by using `this.form.disable();`

I got the expected result trying this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.form.disable();
}
```

The credit in this comment: https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/1000#issuecomment-996626860